# Generate integer random numbers from range (0:10^12)

Tags: r, random, numbers, range

I want to generate 10000 integer random numbers between 0 and 10^12.
Usually, the code would look like this:

```
x <- sample(0:1000000000000,10000,replace=T)
```

But I get following error message:

```
Error in 0:1000000000000 : result would be too long a vector
```

Is there a more memory efficient method that doesn't have to put 10^12 integers in a vector just to get a sample of size 10000? 
If not, is there a way to increase the max size of the vector? I'm working on a 64bit OS with 12GB of free RAM.

Comment: Do they need to be unique?

Comment: Did you estimate the memory requirements of a vector of 10^12 elements? 12 GByte would be not enough.

Comment: Why do you want such a large range?  Essentially what you're asking for is uniform random samples with 12-place precision, and I can't fathom the need for that sort of fine detail.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The real problem lies in the fact that you cannot store the sequence of `0:10^12` into memory. By just defining 0 and 10^12 as boundaries of a uniform distribution, you could get what you seek:

```
runif(10000, 0, 10^12)
[1] 136086417828 280099797063 747063538991 250189170474 589044594904
[6]  65385828028 361086657969 186271687970 338900779840 649082854623  ........
```

This will draw from the uniform distribution (with replacement, though I doubt that matters).

However, what you cannot see is that these are actually floating numbers.

You can use `ceiling` to round them up:

```
samp = runif(1, 0, 10^12)
samp
[1] 19199806033
samp == 19199806033
[1] FALSE
ceiling(samp) == 19199806033
[1] TRUE
```

So the full code would be:

```
ceiling(runif(10000, 0, 10^12))
```

Further nitpicking:

Note that this technically will not allow 0 to be there (since 0.0001 would be rounded up), so you could just draw from

```
ceiling(runif(10000, -1, 10^12))
```

As [Carl Witthoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884372/carl-witthoft) mentions, numbers that do not fit into the size of an integer will not be integers obviously, so you cannot count on these numbers to be integers. You can still count on them to evaluate to `TRUE` when compared to the same floating number without decimals though.

Comment: Except those aren't integers, since `2^31 < 10^12` .  They're still floats, and you may well run into roundoff error if you're not careful.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Isn't that adressed by using `ceiling`?

Comment: `is.integer(ceiling(10^11))  [1] FALSE` .  A `float` with no decimal part is NOT an `integer` so far as the computer is concerned.

Comment: I find it indeed stunning that `is.integer(ceiling(runif(1, -1, 10^12)))` evaluates to `FALSE`. I guess it does not matter for the OP, but this could be a concern for sure. `as.integer` introduces `NA`.

Comment: I get it now, numbers that cannot fit into the space for an integer can obviously not be integerized.

Comment: Remember that integers are limited to 2^31 in almost all programming languages (unless you call long_int in c or something).  And it is important, since integers are stored exactly but floats are stored with mantissa and exponent in binary equivalents, which are inexact.

Comment: You can still represent integral values exactly using doubles up to 2^53, which is just shy of 10^16.

Comment: RE: `ceiling(runif(10000, -1, 10^12))`, it's worth noting that even though this will be fine almost always, there remains a possibility of it returning -1.

Answer (score 23):

I do not understand why you cannot just do...

```
sample(10^12,10,replace=TRUE)
#[1] 827013669653 233988208530 653034892160 564841068001 801391072663 683607493313
#[7] 254556497302 510154570389  51922126428 537709431414
```

> If `x` has `length 1`, is `numeric` (in the sense of `is.numeric`) and `x >= 1`, sampling via sample takes place from `1:x`.

N.B. This does not mean that `sample` has to generate the vector `1:x`!! **@James** points out that for sampling of `0:x` you will need to adjust to `sample(10^12+1,10,replace=TRUE)-1`

Comment: Very much true... so much for first hacking together an answer, then thinking.

Comment: Though 0 is now not included.

Comment: `sample(10^12+1,10,replace=TRUE)-1`

Comment: really? more so than using `ceiling`?

Comment: It completely doesn't matter whether you include zero in the vector of possibilities or not, because the probability of selecting it even if it's there is only 10^(-12)!

Comment: @BenBolker but "I'm sure my special number will win Powerball" :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
floor(runif(10000,min=0,max=(10^12)))
```

Comment: 10^12 would never be returned

Answer (score 1):

```
as.integer(runif(10000, min = 0, max = (1 + 10^12)))
```

FYI: `as.integer` performs a truncation, not a rounding.

In order to test if it works you can try by generating numbers in a smaller interval (i.e. from 0 to 6) and visualize the histogram of the result to see if the result is a uniform distribution, i.e.

```
test <- as.integer(runif(10000, min = 0, max = (6 + 1)))
hist(test)
```

Comment: I was looking for similar idea... I used `m <- as.integer(runif(10000, min = 0, max = (1 + 10^12)))` BUT found `NAs introduced by coercion to integer range` Therefore use with caution.  Where `m <- ceiling(runif(10000, -1, 10^12))` did not produce NAs.

Answer (score 0):

The package `extraDistr` provides a range of additional probability distributions to sample from, including a **discrete uniform distribution**.

Random sampling with function `rdunif` works like other `stats` random sampling functions included with R like `runif`, and avoids needing to round as in other solutions:

```
> library("extraDistr")
> rdunif(n = 10000, min = 0, max = 10^12)
[1] 699559531175 881392957410 315869810758 941600866616
[5] 906084092567 681591022527 514061764115 122652820777
[9] 583204373950 517842726316 741211620393 422150962055 ...
```